Different behavior of Visual Studio for different Exceptions in C#
I have been writing simple console app to learn Exceptions in C#. In my code I have simple try-catch block and when there is, for example, NullReferenceException, Visual Studio jumps and shows the exception as if there is a breakpoint in that line, then I can continue execution manually.
But when there is another kind of exception in program, lets say ArgumentNullException, the program executes normally and finishes.
Consider this code:
string[] myArray = {null};
try
{
    Console.WriteLine(myArray[0].GetType());
}
catch (NullReferenceException x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.Message);
}

In the above code when the NullReferenceException occurs, it jumps from console window, to Visual Studio.
But in the code below, it executes normally and stays on the console window:
string[] myArray = {null};
try
{
    Console.WriteLine(Int32.Parse(myArray[0]));
}
catch (ArgumentNullException x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.Message);
}

Does Visual Studio treat different kinds of exceptions, differently in debug mode?


Does Visual Studio treat different kinds of exceptions, differently in debug mode?

Yes, depending on your exceptions settings (found in Debug > Windows > Exception Settings):

You can choose for different types of exception independently, whether to break when thrown even if the exception gets caught, or to only break if the exception is unhandled.
